# How to create a cron job to upload files to an FTP server

Tags: networking, unix, cron, cronjob

I would like to create a cron job that uploads files from a directory on my computer to my FTP server.  I would like it to do it daily at midnight.  I know pretty much nothing about cron, so I apologize if I sound stupid!

Comment: This should go on to superuser.com as this is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 11):

This is an FTP sample script to transfer one file: (Note you can use an FQDN instead of IP)

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is the file name for the you want to tranfer
# usage: this_script  <filename>
IP_address="xx.xxx.xx.xx"
username="remote_ftp_username"
domain = sample.domain.ftp
password= password

ftp -n > ftp_$$.log <<EOF
 verbose
 open $IP_address
 USER $username $password
 put $1
 bye
EOF
```

Add the `> ftp_$$.log` only if you need logging.
Then you can use the

```
crontab -e
```

command to edit the cronjob table and add your script.

This is an Example:

If you liked to have a the script above, (assume you have it in home and its name is myscript.sh) /home/myscript.sh, run every day at 2am, you have to do:

```
# crontab -e
```

and then you have to add the following entry:

```
0 2 * * * /home/myscript.sh
```

As a reference, here you have a crontab entry parameters meaning:

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

[This tutorial](http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/) could also help you.

Answer (score 0):

[man crontab](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) will show you what you need. You'll want something like:

```
0 0 * * *  yourScript.sh
```

in your crontab file. Note that scripts under `cron` run with a cut-down environment, so you'll have to specify your env settings that the script requires in that script.