# Compress, encrypt and upload a directory to an FTP server in Linux

Tags: linux, encryption

I want to accomplish something rather simple (at least it would seem to be):

1. Compress a directory
2. Encrypt the compressed file
3. Upload the compressed & encrypted file via FTP

I also want to accomplish this in an automated fashion on Linux server.

TrueCrypt is not really an option in this case as it seems it can't compress a single file. Instead you have to make a volume that you mount and move the files into.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/144198/how-to-create-a-cron-job-to-upload-files-to-an-ftp-server) answers how to do the the upload and I know how to compress a directory. It is just the encryption that's giving me problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I've used [`bcrypt`](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) for this pretty happily.</s> Actually, I'm using [`gpg`](http://www.gnupg.org/) now. (Just checked, it's been *that* long since I automated the process involved. I don't recall why I switched, but I *think* it may have been that I felt `gpg` was easier to script.) My command line looks like this:

```
gpg -r RECIP --output OUTPUT_FILE_NAME --encrypt INPUT_FILE_NAME
```

...where

- `RECIP` is the name of the key I want to use (the `-r` is for "recipient;" `gpg` mostly started life as a means of encrypting email; don't let that bother you, it's general-purpose).
- `OUTPUT_FILE_NAME` is the output (encrypted) file
- `INPUT_FILE_NAME` is the input file (cleartext) file

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason that you have to use FTP? Because if not, then SCP is going to be a better option. First because it uses an encrypted channel to send the files (no cleartext passwords for Google StreetView cars to record :-), second because it can use private key authentication, and third because it's really meant for copying.

Regardless, `tar` is the standard way to create a single file out of a directory, and the `-z` switch will use GZIP compression.

```
tar -zcvf OUTFILE.tgz DIRECTORY
```

Then you need to encrypt it. I use `ccrypt`, but there are other options. And maybe there are reasons not to use it that I don't know about.

```
ccrypt -k KEYFILE OUTFILE.tgz
```

Finally, copy it to your destination server. I'll assume that you have a "Transfer" directory under your home directory, and have set up private-key authentication.

```
scp OUTFILE.tgz.cpt YOURHOST:Transfer
```

If FTP really is a requirement, you can use `curl` to do the transfer. I've never done this myself (and have no FTP server with which to try it), but a quick read of the manpage indicates the following:

```
curl --upload-file OUTFILE.tgz.cpt -u USER:PASSWORD ftp:://YOURHOST/HOSTPATH
```

Comment: Yes, there is a reason I have to use FTP.

ccrypt has no keys or are they created/stored separately?

Comment: Although the other answer seems to be what you want, I'll leave mine for someone else. I've edited to mention `curl`, and how to get a key from a file; `man ccrypt` will give you more info.